# Group by on multiple columns in the same table

Tags: sql

Table Employee:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ emp_id  emp_position  emp_start_date employer_id  ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1234    Associate       08/08/08        7657      ║
║ 1234    Associate       01/01/11        3345      ║
║ 1234    Manager         04/03/13        9483      ║
║ 1234    Manager         04/05/15        2345      ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

How to I construct a query to get the oldest date per emp_role and the query should return only the employee who have held more than one post.

select smp.emp_id, smp.emp_position, smp.cnt from ( select emp_id, emp_position, count(*) as cnt from employee group by emp_id, emp_position) smp where smp.cnt > 1

Comment: SELECT e.[emp_position], MIN(e.[emp_start_date]) FROM Employee e GROUP BY e.[emp_position]

Pretty basic stuff....

Comment: Too quick to down vote, huh? I was still editing the format of the table and question. 
select smp.emp_id, smp.emp_position, smp.cnt  from (
select emp_id, emp_position, count(*) as cnt from 
employee 
group by emp_id, emp_position) smp where smp.cnt > 1

Comment: @javadee Add your query into the question as well, rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
select 
  emp_position,
  min(emp_start_date)
from
  Employee
group by
  emp_position
```

Comment: I was able to get the result with slight modification: 
select 
  emp_id, 
  emp_position,
  min(emp_start_date), 
  count(*) 
from
  Employee
group by
  emp_id
  emp_position
having count(*) > 1

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
SELECT emp_position, MIN(emp_start_date)
FROM Employee
GROUP BY emp_position
```